# HTML input pattern customizing validation message causes error

Tags: javascript, html

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v45hrqs1/7/

So, I build a small form in HTML using `pattern` attribute to check if a valid filename is given. Its working, so when I input something like `filename/` and press enter, this will be caught an I get the message "Please match the request format".

Then I wanted a more customized message so I added the javascript part. Now, when I input a invalid filename and press enter, the new message will be shown, so far so good.

HOWEVER, when I now change the filename to a valid one, I still get the error message.

What did I do wrong? My idea is after I change the filename, `var input` is not updated. But I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. I entered `filename/` and got an error message, then I deleted the `/ `so that the field just contains `filename` and it succeeded. Is this the same way you did test your code?

Comment: did you uncomment the javascript part? As I said, the error only occurs with my customized message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need JavaScript for this. You can just set the validity checks on the input themselves like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="packet_name" name="packet_name" pattern="[^\\/:\x22*?<>|]+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Invalid character in name:\n \ / : * ? < >.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" maxlength="100" required>
```

And `oninput` will clear out the custom validity so it will be re-evaluated when it is changed.

Comment: Thx a lot! Works like a charm. I modified it a little since I'm trying jquery and I want to separate html and js part.

Comment: Yeah you can do what ever you want but glad I could be helpful to you :)